# Fine Uploader 3.9 drag and drop support in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, fine-uploader

I am working on upgrading our fine uploader implementation to 4.1 along with ASP.NET server side support.  In the meantime I am trying to address a problem we are experiencing with the 3.9 implementation.  Drag and drop works fine in chrome, firefox, but does not seem to work in IE.

I have been trying to find a live example of 3.9 to test with IE, to determine if it is how we have implemented fine uploader.  The best live example I could find was here: http://ployanich-ubuntu.dyndns-ip.com/demos/fine-uploader2/

When testing the drag and drop in IE, with that example, it also seems to not work.

I tried looking to see if this was already acknowledged for version 3.9, but again I was not able to find anything directly addressing this problem.

Our current implementation using fine uploader 3.9 is at http://www.getalink.com

You can test the drag and drop in other browsers, again they seem to work, IE is the problem.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop uploading is not possible in IE9 and older due to lack of File API support.  This is documented in the [browser support feature matrix](http://docs.fineuploader.com/browser-support.html).

Comment: I did see that feature matrix, but it is for 4.2, I was unable to locate the feature matrix for 3.9.  I understand that IE9 does not support drag and drop, however in both our implementation and the example implementation referred to above, drag and drop does not appear to be working with IE 11.  Are you able to confirm that 3.9 drag and drop works in IE 11?  I just tried it again in IE 11 and still got a sporadic drop zone blinking on and off.

Comment: DnD does not work in IE11 in version 3.9.  [Support for IE11](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/933) wasn't added until 4.1.  IE10 DnD should work in 3.9 though.

Comment: @sthede, we have archival documentation for all of our tagged releases. Check out: http://docs.fineuploader.com/tag/